# Why boolean on left when comparing in if?

Tags: php

why some people do this:

```
if(false == $var) {prettyThigs();}
```

instead of this:

```
if($var == false) {prettyThigs();}
```

The second options is the one i most see and more natural for me to read.

Thanks!

Comment: Because they're really scared of missing an `=` and instead of checking the value of something, changing it.

Comment: `if($var=false) {uglyThingsMayOccur();}`

Comment: Its an old practice to avoid assignment error `if($var = false)` IDE is likely a better option.

Comment: [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: @Steve there are circumstances where your only IDE is vim.

Comment: vim is a much better IDE, think if notepad is the IDE you get

Comment: @simon Nice, i didn't know the name of this, Thank you.